# CLLocationManager Precision and Power Consumption

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I know that `CLLocationManager` provides us with multiple precision choice, so it does not constantly send you a bunch of notification. But does it saves power?

I'm looking to do a geofencing application that reminds me to get off the bus. LOL

Comment: It's hard to save power when you implement that function.

Comment: Obviously, significant change service uses much less power, too. Maybe use significant change service as you're going between distant stations, and only turn on more accurate location services as you get closer. The region monitoring service would seem like it would be idea, though it says that it might take a few minutes, so that might not be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power consumption is dependent on the desiredAccuracy setting of the LocationManager. If you set it to kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation then the power consumption is the highest.

In your scenario you could potentially use kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer as the bus stops should be at least a Kilometer apart.

Comment: But the GPS is still constantly running, isn't it? So why would it matter?

Comment: See [Tips for Conserving Battery](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW17).

Comment: Well in case of kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer the gps may not be running but rather the distance is derived from cell towers.